# My functions definition give different result when I saved as tools.py file

Tags: python, function, apply

I have written two functions in Jupiter lab. When I integrated those to transfer it to a `tools.py` file and imported in Jupyter lab, I get different results. Can anyone tell me what the difference is?

Actually, the functions are for converting a kind of nested data frame to a flat data frame. I feel the problem is in a way that I used to apply function with two arguments

Here is my code in jupyter lab:

```
def findTS(s):
    out=""
    for i,r in om.iterrows():
        sci=r["sec_ID"]
        if sci in s:
            out=r["type_sec"]

            exit
    return(out)
```

```
def Js2Geodf(df): 
# df=OmegaJ["chapters"][0]
    om=json_normalize(df,"section")
    om=om.dropna(subset=["sec_part"])
    l=[]
    for i,x in om.iterrows():
        k={"type_sec":x["type_sec"]}
        l.append([x["sec_part"]])
        listItems=list(flatten_list(l))
        dfout=pd.DataFrame(listItems)
        dfout["type_sec"]=dfout.apply(lambda x: findTS(x["ID"]),axis=1)
        return(dfout)
```

Then I integrated those in a way that I can use them independently as a method in module `tools.py`

```
def findTS(s,df):
    out=""
    om=json_normalize(df,"section")
    for i,r in om.iterrows():
        sci=r["sec_ID"]
        if sci in s:
            out=r["type_sec"]

            exit
    return(out)
```

```
def Js2Geodf(df): 
# df=OmegaJ["chapters"][0]
    om=json_normalize(df,"section")
    om=om.dropna(subset=["sec_part"])
    l=[]
    for i,x in om.iterrows():
        k={"type_sec":x["type_sec"]}
        l.append([x["sec_part"]])
    listItems=list(flatten_list(l))
    dfout=pd.DataFrame(listItems)
    dfout["type_sec"]=dfout.apply(lambda x: findTS(x["ID"],df),axis=1)
    return(dfout)
```

As you see in each function, there are some small changes.

In the first function:

```
-def findTS(s)--->def findTS(s,df)
-adding ....om=json_normalize(df,"section")
```

In the second function in the last line:

```
-dfout["type_sec"]=dfout.apply(lambda x: findTS(x["ID"]),axis=1)-->
-dfout["type_sec"]=dfout.apply(lambda x: findTS(x["ID"],df),axis=1)
```

The problem is that it gives me different results, I am kind of suspicious regarding the usage of apply and lambda with two arguments.

Comment: What's *exit* supposed to do there? It doesn't do what you think it does, and if it did, that would be a bad design decision. Also you seem to use *om* in both function. Make that an argument instead of *df*.

Comment: @CristiFati many thanks for the prompt response, since the df is my data as datafrmae, I put as an argument. I think it is more related to this part :                              ``` dfout["type_sec"]=dfout.apply(lambda x: findTS(x["ID"],df),axis=1)``` is init it?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to figure things out without actual data, but here's **one** thing that might be responsible:

1. Original variant:

   - *Js2Geodf*:

     ```py
     # ...
     om = json_normalize(df, "section")  # @TODO - cfati: MARKED LINE 1
     om = om.dropna(subset=["sec_part"])  # @TODO - cfati: MARKED LINE 2
     # ...
     ```
   - *findTS*:

     ```py
     # ...
     for i, r in om.iterrows():
     # ...
     ```

   In *findTS*, you operate on the *om* variable (from *Js2Geodf*) resulted after executing *MARKED LINE **2***
2. Modified variant:

   - *Js2Geodf*:

     Things are exactly the same as in ***#1.***
   - *findTS*:

     ```py
     # ...
     om = json_normalize(df, "section")  # @TODO - cfati: Identical to MARKED LINE 1
     for i, r in om.iterrows():
     # ...
     ```

   In *findTS*, you operate on the *om* variable which is defined here, and its definition is identical to *MARKED LINE **1***, as a consequence:

   - You're **missing** *MARKED LINE **2***
   - It's also highly inefficient to execute this line every time *findTS* is called

As I stated in a comment (at that point I only saw a *design* flaw, now it's clear that it's also a *semantic* flaw in the code), pass *om* as an argument instead of *df*. 
Here's the code (I did some small improvements as well, there's a lot of room to improve further, but I didn't follow the logic, so I didn't change it):

```py
def findTS(s, om):
    for i, r in om.iterrows():
        sci = r["sec_ID"]
        if sci in s:
            return r["type_sec"]
    return ""


def Js2Geodf(df): 
    #df = OmegaJ["chapters"][0]
    om = json_normalize(df, "section")
    om = om.dropna(subset=["sec_part"])
    l = []
    for i, x in om.iterrows():
        l.append([x["sec_part"]])
    listItems = list(flatten_list(l))
    dfout = pd.DataFrame(listItems)
    dfout["type_sec"] = dfout.apply(lambda x: findTS(x["ID"], om), axis=1)
    return dfout
```

***@EDIT0***:

Summarizing information from comments as well:

- *Js2Geodf*'s last 4 lines indentation differs in original and modified variants (I assume it's a typo in the former)
- Make sure **input data is constant** across runs (and different code versions). Apparently, this one generated a lot of headaches, and once solved, the code was working as well

Comment: wow! many thanks for this comprehensive response, I appreciate your time and effort. I have tried still the same problem! I can not find why the result is different!

Comment: Different how? Same as your 2nd attempt? Which output is the correct one? Also note that the last 4 lines of *Js2Geodf* are **indented differently** (in the original variant are part of the loop) !!!

Comment: thank you for the responses,  they have a different result, some extra line is added in the new version like before!I also changed as you told.  I do not know why..It is really headache..any idea

Comment: I have done! all you told! it does not work, It is very important for me to transfer everything to tolls, can you give me some hints

Comment: actually now it works, it turned out that new data has not been actualized! sorry about that! however all solutions work now, I can convince myself we have a better design for the function now, many thanks for your time!

Comment: Good to hear that! I updated the answer including all new info.